# url share on the facebook but title is change in share link

Tags: php, facebook

i m share the link

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.thebuyerpower.com/index.php/home/projectdetail/gulshanhomz/33

and my site title is

Pre Sales Offer - Gulshan Homz at Sector -143B, Noida in a group with thebuyerpower.com

But on the facebook share title is different that is

Buy property - Gulshan Homz at Sector -143 B, Noidain a group with the buyerpower.com

hows is possible.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this meta property to your site

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Pre Sales Offer - Gulshan Homz at Sector -143B, Noida in a group with thebuyerpower.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the exact title, description, and thumbnail that Facebook Share uses by adding the following meta tags to the **<head>** element in your page, like:

```
<meta name="title" content="Your title here" />
<meta name="description" content="Description here." />
```

Answer (score -1):

You may edit the title before posting it by clicking the title itself.

[image: here]